# how to traverse multi-layers complex object in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am still new to firebase and I don't know how to extract array of objects inside **item.compactReports** and then display it on my **home.component.html**.

Note: the length of compactReports is also unknown, it varies for each node.

compactReports =[ {"area":{"0": "some data; more data "}}, ... , {"detail":{"0": "some data"}}]

I hope the output will be like:

```
 <td> area: some data <br> 
  ....(some more lines depends on each object)...<br>
      detail: some data <br>
 </td>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  reports$; 
  constructor(angularData: AngularFireDatabase,homeService: HomeService) {
    this.reports$ = homeService.getData();  
   } 
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of reports$ | async">
                <td>{{item.type}}</td>
                <td>{{item.compactReports}}</td> // ***stuck here
                <td>latitude:{{item.latitude}}<br>
                     longitude:{{item.longitude}}</td>
                <td>{{item.phoneNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{item.timestamp}}</td>
              </tr>
```

**home.service.ts**

```
export class HomeService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getData(){
    return this.db.list('/Reports');

  }
}
```

[My data structure in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mwwy.png)

Comment: Could you give an example of how you want to display item.compactReports in the page? Also, do you know the keys of all possible items in item.compactReports?

Comment: I updated the question. I don't know what key and how many of them will belong to compactReports. I am working on emergency app that let user reports accidents. Each accidents have different reports elements that make it unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Given that 'reports$' is an array of item objects and 'compactReports' of each item is an array of key-value pairs, you can define a custom function (I name it 'listDetails') to evaluate 'compactReports' and manipulate the result. Note that Angular interpolation {{...}} output the result as plain text, so if you need to display html tags you will need the property [innerHtml].

#### home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    ......

    listDetails( compactReports : {}[] ) {
        let result : string = "";
        for (let i in compactReports) {
            let keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(compactReports[i]);
            for (let j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
                result += keys[j] + ": " + compactReports[i][keys[j]] + "<br>";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

#### home.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of reports$ | async">
    ......

    <td [innerHtml]="listDetails(item.compactReports)"></td>

    ......
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I got error from the solution. Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:Unexpected closing tag "td". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags                                                                                             <td>{{item.type}}</td>
<td[innerHtml]="listDetails(item.compactReports)">[ERROR ->]</td>

Comment: Your td tag should not stick to the attribute. <td [innerHtml]... instead of <td[innerHtml]...

Comment: thanks so much, you are so helpful. I have been stuck for 5 hours because of this. Now it s 2am and i can sleep in peace.

Comment: It depends on your supplied parameter. If you are using my exact function, then try changing the line 'result += keys[j] + ...' to 'result += i + ...' It's all about how many levels of data are nested in your parameter.

Comment: thanks. i replace keys[j] with i . It works beautifully now. I am very new with angular and json. beside Angular.io what other resources that you have been using to learn about the subject? thanks

Comment: Angular.io has all the documentations, but it's not easy to learn from there. I usually search here for answers because most of the time people will have the same questions I have. There are some good developers who put their work in their blogs or github, so definitely search for their tutorials and you will learn fast.

Comment: what does it mean when you type " compactReports : { }[ ] ". Can you elaborate on that ? thanks. I know [ ] is array but { } [ ] is very strange to me.

Comment: It means the parameter 'compactReports' is an array of objects that do not have defined structures. Though not necessary, I like to define the type my parameters in TypeScript so if I am using the parameter incorrectly I can be notified by intellisense. Without setting the type, it's 'any' by default.